# Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

i have a string like that:

```
[variable = value][variable2=value2][Some text inside]
```

I need to make a Regular Expression that can give me matches as groups, so in my MathCollection I should have

```
matches[0] = [variable = value]
matches[1] = [variable2=value2]
matches[2] = [Some text inside]
```

Can somebody to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(\[.*?\])
```

http://regexr.com?2trpv

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that but it hadn't worked, because the Regular Expression in C# is different.

Comment: Sorry, i tried it again and it works fine, i did this: 
`Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\[.*?\])");` 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mallok Yeah, of course you had to use verbatim strings or escape `\\`. I just gave the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex getStuff = new Regex("(\[.*?\])");
MatchCollection matches = getStuff.Matches(inputString);
```

Comment: It works fine, I did this, it just needs a @ before the first " on the constructor.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A one liner which gives you an array of the strings you wanted:

```
var strings = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\[.*?\])").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.ToString()).ToArray();
```